# UI Automation propertychangedevents not triggering on QT app

Tags: c#, qt, ui-automation

I am using .net ui automation to get the state and properties of several controls on a QT application. The problem I'm facing is that some `AutomationPropertyChangedEvent`s never trigger. I'm able to see the properties of these controls using tools like Inspect or UIAVerify.

For now I have set a timer to manually get the values from `AutomationElements` but I was hoping to get the events working for better accuracy.

A snippet of my code:

```
window = AutomationElement.FromHandle(qtAppProcess.MainWindowHandle);
Condition textPaneCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "pane");
Condition channelTabCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "tab");

AutomationElement textPane = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, textPaneCondition);

//this one works
Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(
    window, 
    TreeScope.Element, 
    eventHandler1 = new AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(OnWindowStateChanged),
    WindowPattern.WindowVisualStateProperty);

//never works
Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(
    window, 
    TreeScope.Element, 
    eventHandler2= new AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(OnTopmostChanged),
    WindowPattern.IsTopmostProperty);

//never works
Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(
    textPane, 
    TreeScope.Element, 
    eventHandler3 = new AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(OnBoundsChanged),
    AutomationElement.BoundingRectangleProperty);
//etc..
```

Eventhandler:

```
//triggers correctly
private void OnWindowStateChanged(object sender, AutomationPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Property == WindowPattern.WindowVisualStateProperty)
    {
        // minimize, restore
        var state = (WindowVisualState)e.NewValue;
        if (state == WindowVisualState.Minimized)
        {
            //do thing
        }
    }
}
//never triggers
private void OnTopmostChanged(object sender, AutomationPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Property == WindowPattern.IsTopmostProperty)
    {
            //always on top enabled/disabled
    }
}
//etc..
```

Edit: Tried with caching

```
request = new CacheRequest();
request.TreeScope = TreeScope.Element | TreeScope.Children;
request.Add(AutomationElement.BoundingRectangleProperty);
request.Add(AutomationElement.NameProperty);
using(request.Activate())
{
    window = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process[0].MainWindowHandle);
    textPane = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, textPaneCondition);
    channelTab = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, channelTabCondition);
    Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(InvokePattern.InvokedEvent, channelTab, TreeScope.Element, OnChannelInvoked);
    // of these only window bounds event is triggering
    Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(window, TreeScope.Element, new AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(OnWindowBoundsChanged), AutomationElement.BoundingRectangleProperty);
    Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(channelTab, TreeScope.Element, new AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(OnChannelNameChanged), AutomationElement.NameProperty);
    Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(textPane, TreeScope.Element, new AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(OnPaneBoundsChanged), AutomationElement.BoundingRectangleProperty);
}
```

But sadly there was no change, the only events triggering are window state and bounds.

Comment: Some properties only work from cached elements and not current elements. Could you trying using a cache request and caching the changed events you are interested in. The only one I know for certain works this way is checking if a window closed but I wouldn't be surprised if more worked this way.

Comment: @MaxYoung Sadly caching didn't help (hoping I did it correctly), most events still aren't triggering.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is an outstanding bug with WinForms. You can track its progress here: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/7261#issuecomment-1149334904